# Typescript different arrays in object

Tags: typescript

I have an object for instance:

```
const obj = {
  arr1: [100, 30, 10],
  arr2: ['hello', 'hello', 'hello']
}
```

Typescript can't define type of obj, what type shouled I assign to obj? I tried

```
const obj: [number,number,number] | [string,string,string]  {}
```

but it didn't work, TS2322 error, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example type annotation `obj: [number,number,number] | [string,string,string]` typescript cannot see that you meant an object - it thinks you meant `obj` is *either* a three-tuple of numbers, or a three-tuple of strings.

I'm guessing you want something more like this:

```
// inferred type is { arr1: number[], arr2: string[] }
const obj1 = {
  arr1: [100, 30, 10],
  arr2: ['hello', 'hello', 'hello']
}

// no compiler error because obj2 matches obj1
const obj2: { arr1: number[]; arr2: string[]; } = obj1
```